# What's a word for "desire to improve myself"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that captures the idea of "desire to self-improve," but does not imply that I have (yet) actually taken any action.

I'm thinking of something along these lines:
When I noticed that my health was poor, I wanted to improve myself [new word here].  Only then did I sign up for a gym class.

Comment: .........ambition......

Comment: What's your *motivation* for asking this question?

Answer (score 2):

You could say you have an **[aspiration](http://tfd.com/aspiration)** for self-improvement.

> A strong desire for high achievement.

Comment: I think aspiration (or aspirations) is good as it implies that you haven't actually achieved the aims yet, which is one of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **better myself** and **get better**.

> I don't study, I want to better myself.
>
> I'm sad but I want to get better.

## Resources

[Get Better](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/get-better)

[Better myself](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/better+myself)

Comment: ... want **to** ...

Answer (score 0):

When I noticed that my health was poor, I wanted to **shape up**. Only then did I sign up for a gym class.

When I noticed that my health was poor, I **became motivated**. Only then did I sign up for a gym class.

My recognition of my poor health **motivated** me to sign up for a gym class.